# What is the Flux State?

Tags: shadowrun-dragonfall, shadowrun

Simply as that... What is Flux State? I am in the middle of the game, now, and I can guess a little. But Internet has no clear explanation of the thing. Is this a place, or ideology? Or maybe a place when certain ideology has been applied? Is the word used only around Berlin? The more information the better. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flux State refers to the period when the anarchists ruled [Berlin](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Berlin).

> In 2039, after a small-scale civil war that had started with the Night of Rage an organization called "Anarchist Movement Berlin" (AMB) gained control of the city and declared Berlin the "Greatest Experiment in Anarchist History".

You can read a little more about it [here](http://shadowrun.gamepedia.com/Berlin):

> In the wake of the anarchist revolution of 2039, the city seceded from the German state and created the **Flux State**. This grand experiment in social order is anarchy in practice, where the power structure constantly evolves and the crafty shadowrunner will always find ways to survive - and even thrive. Corporations thread carefully in the Free City - and even the great dragon Lofwyr only has so much influence here.